# find smallest value in linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, min

having trouble figuring this out, every time i run my code the program goes on forever, everything else in the linked list works perfectly well. including the delete.

```
public Node smallestValue() {
    Node current = firstL;
    int min = current.data;

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        while (current != null) {
            if (min < current.data) {
                min = current.data;
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("empty list");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(min);

    return current;
}
```

Comment: move `current = current.next` out of the `if` statement

Comment: And your condition is wrong. It should be `if (min > current.data)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to advance `current` whether or not `min < current.data`. Just move the assignment to outside the `if`. (Also, as @0x499602D2 points out in a comment, to find the smallest value you need to change `min` when it is *greater* than `current.data`.)

```
while(current != null){
    if(min > current.data){
        min = current.data;
    }
    current = current.next;
}
```

It might be cleaner to do this as a `for` loop:

```
for (Node current = firstL, int min = current.data;
     current != null;
     current = current.next)
{
    min = Math.min(min, current.data);
}
```

Because this is inside the test for an empty list, this has the advantage of not crashing if `firstL` is `null` (which, I assume, cannot happen if the list is not empty).